# Filter at the list comprehension in haskell

Tags: haskell, filter, list-comprehension

I have this list comprehension:

```
[(x,y)| x<-[1..2], y<-[x..3], let z = x+y, odd z]
```

1. The right result is [(1,2),(2,3)], but I can't understand why. What is the filter "let z = x+y, odd z"
   doing? There is no "z" in the other code, so I can't understand why this is changing something.
2. Can somebody explain, step by step, what happens here.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If it helps think it this way `[(x,y)| x<-[1..2], y<-[x..3], odd (x+y)]`.

Comment: `for x in [1,2]: for y in range(x,4): z=x+y; if(odd(z)): yield (x,y)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So x goes from 1 to 2, and y from x to 3.

So for the first one:

```
x = 1
y = 1
z = 1 + 1 = 2
```

z is not odd, therefore, it is not added.
Then:

```
x = 1
y = 2
z = 1 + 2 = 3
```

z is now odd, so it is added.
Then:

```
x = 1
y = 3
z = 1 + 3 = 4
```

z is even, ergo not added.
Then:

```
x = 2
y = 2
z = 2 + 2 = 4
```

z is even.

Then:

```
x = 2
y = 3
z = 2 + 3 = 5
```

z is 5, odd, therefore added.

Answer (score 5):

You're generating tuples, where sum of their elements must be an odd number. The line:

```
let z = x+y, odd z
```

gives name `z` to the sum `x + y`, this value then is used with predicate `odd` to test if the sum is actually odd. Combinations of `x` and `y`, for which `odd z` evaluates to `True` get into the result list, others are removed.

Note that the lowest value for `y` collection is actual value of variable `x`:

```
x <- [1..2]
y <- [x..3]
```

This is to remove some 'duplicates' (`(2,1)`) from consideration.